# Seeding random number generators in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using this function to randomize the x coordinates of one of my sprites:

```
static inline CGFloat skRandf(){
    return rand() / (CGFloat) RAND_MAX;
}
static inline CGFloat skRand(CGFloat low, CGFloat high){
    return skRandf() * (high - low) + low;
}
```

It works fine but if I play the game several times I notice that the x coordinate of my sprite I'm applying it to is the same every time.  Is there a way to change this or seed it with time to fix this problem?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the docs for `rand()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using arc4random() instead as it doesn't require a seed to be set, and uses a more advanced algorithm.

```
static inline CGFloat skRandf(){
    return arc4random() / (CGFloat) RAND_MAX;
}
static inline CGFloat skRand(CGFloat low, CGFloat high){
    return skRandf() * (high - low) + low;
}
```

Comment: RAND_MAX is meant to be used together with rand(), not arc4random(). The man page states arc4random() has twice the range of rand(). Instead, you should divide by UINT32_MAX.

Comment: `arc4random` is also a lot slower than `rand`. For a lot of "random" things in a game you don't need true cryptographic-quality (pseudo)randomness, so sticking to `rand` isn't that bad. See its man page for how use `srand` to seed. (Seeding with the `time()` is pretty good for making sure you don't see the same pattern every time you run the app. On the other hand, making sure you see the same pattern every time you run the app can be good for testing during development.)

Comment: 2nd function should take reminder when divided by the range, not multiply.
`static inline CGFloat skRand(CGFloat low, CGFloat high)
{
    return ((skRandf() % (high - low)) + low);
}`